# How to adjust the gaps that parskip produces?

Tags: paragraphs

So when I use the setting,

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
```

in the preamble to set line gaps between paragraphs then it seems I am getting less gaps than when I explicitly use `~\\ \\` between paragraphs.

Is there a preamble way to get the later kind of gaps?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you try `\setlength{\parskip}{1\baselineskip plus 0.1pt}`?

Comment: This in addition to the 2 lines I already have in the preamble?

Comment: never use `~\\ \\ ` anywhere! It does not make a paragraph break at all.

Comment: It does! I have always used it and it works!

Comment: `~\\ \\` doesn't create a paragraph break, it inserts an empty line, which is a very different beast (although it may look like a paragraph break). You'll see that easily when you have a non-zero parindent, but it also influences e.g. float placement. And it messes up handling of single lines at the start and end of a paragraph.

Comment: @gradstudent Don't argue with David Carlisle. He is one of THE experts. (GUM)

Comment: Often enough I dont know of any other way to a create a line gap. Like between consecutive theorem environments somehow an automatic linegap is not produced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `parskip` package does

```
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5\baselineskip plus 2pt}
```

(and also sets the parindent to zero).

If you *really* want to have a whole blank line between paragraphs,<sup>1</sup> then add

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\parskip}{1\baselineskip plus 2pt}%
}
```

to your document preamble. You can safely remove `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`, instead.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Your readers will hate you.</sub>

Comment: This command "\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip plus 2pt}%
}" apart from having the desired effect is ALSO creating a balnk page at the start with "2pt" written at the top.

Comment: @gradstudent There was a missing `1`, sorry